# MySQL slow group by/order by

Tags: mysql, performance, join, sql-order-by

The following query is relatively slow (0.7 seconds with ~6k rows)

```
SELECT items.*, COUNT(transactions.ID)
   FROM items
  INNER JOIN users ON (items.USER = users.ID)
   LEFT JOIN transactions ON (items.id = transactions.item)
  WHERE items.ACTIVE = 1
    AND items.DELETED_AT IS NULL
  GROUP BY items.ID
  ORDER BY items.DATE DESC
  LIMIT 20
```

But speeds up dramatically when ordered by items.ID DESC instead of items.DATE. The transactions join is to a large table (~250k rows) and is one-to-many. The date column has an index.

Is there any way to generically improve the performance of the ORDER BY?

EDIT: indexes on items.user, transactions.item, and items.date. Items has 49 columns, users 76, and transactions 17.

Comment: Can you provide the schemas and especially the indexes for the the three tables?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is first selecting items filtered by your WHERE clause and ordered by date in a subquery, (or in a view, if MySQL does not support ORDER BY in subqueries,) and then in an enclosing query do your joins. (I am not writing this as an answer because SO discourages speculative answers.)

Comment: Have you tried including `items.DATE` in `GROUP BY` (in the first position too)?

Answer (score 5):

Indexes can affect the performance of `ORDER BY` clauses.  This [MySQL manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) is probably worth your time.  Essentially, if you order by a column that is part of the index that MySQL uses for the query, MySQL can use the index for the sort rather than the data itself.

In your particular query, the fact that the `DATE` column has an index doesn't matter, since that index probably isn't being used in your query.  Your `WHERE` statement contains `items.ACTIVE` and `items.DELETED_AT`, and if those columns have an index that's being used for the `WHERE` that doesn't include the `DATE` column, then MySQL can't use the index to sort by `DATE`, and is likely resorting to a file sort.

If you can come up with an index that can be used by both the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`, you'd get an optimization boost.  In this case, `items.ACTIVE` seems like a low cardinality column, so assuming `items.DELETED_AT` is a date, I would probably try an index like `INDEX(DELETED_AT,DATE)` for that table.

Use [`EXPLAIN SELECT...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) to see more about what's going on there too, you might get some further insights.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE 1 GROUP BY ID limit 0,10) as X
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

The above query works perfect , i have used it in a very long database . It ORDER BY the listing of 10 OR (xx) items which we are getting from inner select query, so it's very fast!

Comment: You are not even using Left_join

Answer (score 1):

These are things that COULD (read not guaranteed) help.

1. Eliminate the * on items.* and list each field individually. 49
   columns is a lot; do you really need them all?
2. Usually the engine optimizes the queries such that limiting
   criteria is considered on joins.  Perhaps the plan used by the
   engine is not doing this (need explain plan results to know)  so
   re-arranging the where clause and joins MAY (not likely) help by
   forcing the engine to consider this. (See below)
3. Rebuild table statistics if many update, insert, deletes have
   occurred over time, it's possible the table statistics are off and
   need to be
   [rebuilt](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)
   for each table

```
SELECT items.[list fields], COUNT(transactions.ID)
   FROM items
  INNER JOIN users ON (items.USER = users.ID)
        AND items.Active=1 
        AND items.DELETED_AT is Null
   LEFT JOIN transactions ON (items.id = transactions.item)
  GROUP BY items.ID
  ORDER BY items.DATE DESC
  LIMIT 20
```